# Python Tornado render static directory

Tags: python, webserver, tornado

I am trying to serve a page from a static directory using the Tornado API in Python. [This answer is similar to what I am trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988185/tornado-python-self-renderexample-html-ignores-css), but I can't seem to get it to work.

My directory structure looks like this (all of the static files are inside a folder called `web`):

[image: directory file structure]

I have a webserver setup like this:

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r'/ws', WSHandler),
            (r'/', IndexHandler),
        ]
        settings = {
            "debug": True,
            "static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "web")
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)

http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
http_server.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I thought this line:

```
"static_path": os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "web")
```

might have fixed the problem, but when I point to the `index.html` file:

```
class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        self.render('web/index.html')
```

It serves the page as expected, but prints this error message to the console:

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /css/reset.css (::1) 3.57ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /js/lib/custom-marker.js (::1) 0.96ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /js/map.js (::1) 2.08ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /js/websocket-client.js (::1) 1.56ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /css/index.css (::1) 0.89ms
```

In this minimalistic example, how do I fix my problem? Where is it trying to point and not being able to find the files?

Any help you could offer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation section on [Static files and aggressive file caching](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/running.html), prefixing your "css" and "js" urls with "web" should solve your problem. For example:

`/css/reset.css` should be `/web/css/reset.css`

Or just use the recommended `static_url` in your templates (if you're using them):

```
{{ static_url("css/reset.css") }}
```

Comment: Exactly. quoting: "This setting will automatically make all requests that start with /static/ serve from that static directory, e.g., http://localhost:8888/static/foo.png will serve the file foo.png from the specified static directory. "

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you can specify wildcard to the static dir's to render all the files from specified directory,at the time while initializing the application

```
app = web.Application([
    (r'/', IndexHandler),
    (r'/js/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './static/js'}),
    (r'/css/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './static/css'}),
    (r'/images/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './static/images'}),

])
```

above code will map all static URL's accordingly,

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

will be mapped to `/static/js` dir,

```
(r'/js/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './static/js'})
```

And so , all the css, and images to their respective mappers,

```
(r'/css/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './static/css'}),
(r'/images/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './static/images'}),
```

Comment: Awesome! that helped.