# Cannot link to CSS in HTML

Tags: html, css

I cannot link to CSS in HTML but the paths are right. I've tried everything, even magic isn't helping.

- HTML path is `romanchenko_test_task/templates/hello.html`
- CSS path is `romanchenko_test_task/static/first-style.css`

hello.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/first-style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Hello world </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

first-style.css:

```
body {
     background: blue;
     color: white;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: This would likely work on a server, but not for your local testing. The slash always brings you back to the root.

Comment: The answer given by @Jdsfighter will work for sure. Adding ../ before a folder will point to the root of the child folder . In your case ,root of the /static/ i.e romanchenko_test_tas.

Comment: @Meeseeks, I use tornado web server, so when I run "python main.py", I get "WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/first-style.css (127.0.0.1) 0.65ms"

Comment: @ItAssistors, nope, it didn't help.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629797/python-tornado-render-static-directory) will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyone.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/first-style.css">
```

is linking CSS to HTML right. My problem was that I've forgot to write a handler for static files (*.css), so tornado (python framework) couldn't identify them.

Hendlers should look like:

```
handlers=[(r'/', MainHandler)],
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
    static_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static"),
    debug=True)
```

Answer (score 8):

Your relative links are incorrect.

Your two folder paths are:

```
romanchenko_test_task/templates/hello.html
romanchenko_test_task/static/first-style.css
```

So to get out of your `templates` folder, you need to go up 1 level by using `../`

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/first-style.css">
```

Comment: Alternatively if you are running a web server will have a document root and then your original path should work, because `/` will point to `romanchenko_test_task`. Try MAMP if you don't have a dev web server set up – it is quick and easy.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. I've got 404 GET /static/first-style.css

Comment: I use Linux, so MAMP doesn't fit.

Comment: What are you using to serve your pages? LAMP?

Answer (score 0):

The directory you are calling the CSS from is incorrect.
You should use `C:/romanchenko_test_task/static/first-style.css` (the entire directory) to call it.

Comment: That is **not** good practice, as it will only work on your personal computer, assuming the files are stored directly in the `C:/` directory, which I highly doubt.