# Create .html file with tornado with link to static css

Tags: python, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tornado

Using Tornado, i want to create an html file and save it to re-use it later. Inside the html i want a reference to the bootstrap css in my static files.

My simplfied html looks like this, following [Tornado/Python self.render("example.html") ignores CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988185/tornado-python-self-renderexample-html-ignores-css)

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{static_url('app/content/bootstrap.css')}}" />
</head>

<body>
{{name}}
</body>
</html>
```

My simplified .py looks like this:

```
import tornado.template
loader=tornado.template.Loader(r"C:\templateDirectory")
output_from_parsed_template= loader.load("template.html").generate(name="John")

# to save the results
file = open(r"C:\templateDirectory\result.html","w")
file.write(output_from_parsed_template)
file.close()
```

However, i get the message:

> NameError: name 'static_url' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Many of the predefined names for use in Tornado templates come from `RequestHandler`, rather than the template system itself (because they need Application-level configuration). To use `static_url` as-is, you'll need the whole serving stack, not just a Loader and Template.generate (or you can dig into the code and reconstruct what it's doing).

Comment: Thanks Ben Darnell. Could you point me towards an example on how templates with static_url are done in Tornado?

Comment: Search for `static_url` in `tornado/web.py`.